# Align part of listview items to top and part to the bottom

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, actionbarsherlock, drawer

I have a listview in the actionbarsherlock drawer matching its full size for switching between frames. I want to align 4 listitems from the listview to the top and 3 to the bottom of the drawer. Any idea how to do it ? First idea was to calculate the space in the middle and create one empty listitem with such height. But I did not found a way how to do it.
Or any better idea ?

**edit1:**
Understood, but I want to do it in the code not xml. I have a draer_main.xml where is a LinearLayout listview. and then a drawer_list_item where I have LinearLayout in which there is specified how item looks like. This is the used in the code and for each item is written some text + added picture

inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);

So I tried to set the itemView params as you proposed but there is always an error cause java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

**edit2:** Tried to use AbsListView.LayoutParams, but this has not parameter weight !?!

Answer (score 0):

**Simple!**

Create a `View` to fill the space between the top 4 listitems and the bottom 3 listitems.

**Example:**

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```